# CSS transitions not working in IE 8/7, works in IE 11-9, FF, Chrome, Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

I am using a js counter which works great in FF, Chrome, safari, IE 11-9 but for some reason the transitions are not working in ie 8/7 (see css code below).The top image is the counter in FF, Chrome, safari, IE 11-9. The second image is from ie8/7.  Not sure what I am missing, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
.prev-top {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.prev-top.flip {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

[image: counter]

[image]

Comment: Transform is not supported in IE<9 http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Please don't use tags like JavaScript and jQuery when they have absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: thanks for the response... That's what I was thinking... appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `transform` is [**not supported in IE<9**](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) (nor indeed is any other form of CSS animation), you will likely need to resort to another means of animation, such as `.gif`s (shudder)

Comment: I'm not a front end developer, but a library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) probably is a good place to start with building out the proper framework to support this in IE

Comment: @ejhost Modernizr is great, but all it can do here is tell you whether they're supported or not :)